# What is the single best free Eclipse plugin for authoring and editing XML documents?

Tags: xml, eclipse

In my old job I used XMLSpy to do my XML authoring and editing, but now I require a free plugin for Eclipse to do this. My basic requirements are:

```
- General XML document editing
- Creating XSD files
- Creating WSDL files
```

Can you recommend a free Eclipse plugin for this?

Comment: just discovered my personal favorite, Rinzo XML editor, a free and open source XML editor plugin (and XSD/DTD generator, even integrates with JDT), which is still actively developed:
http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the free department, [**WTP** (Web Tools Platform)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/index.php) (in its latest version) does include a lot of features,
including [schema creation/modification](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.xsdeditor.doc.user/topics/cxmlsced.html).

Comment: Web Tool Plateform has editors for XML, XSD and WSDL ; for all there is a "source" mode (text editor with some features like coloration...) and "design" mode (graphical) but I never use the second...

Answer (score 6):

There's an official Eclipse plugin for editing XMLs. It is part of the [Eclipse WebTools project](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/). You can install it from the update site at   ***http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates***.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you!

**[XML Eclipse Editor & XMLBuddy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecxml/)**

Comment: This plugin is old and link to the homepage was broken, where I can find correct version of this plugin?

Comment: Here it is - http://download.cnet.com/XMLBuddy/3000-7241_4-10422909.html

Answer (score 1):

I have positive experience with tiny [xmlbuddy](http://www.xmlbuddy.com/) plugin for editing xml documents in eclipse (plain and xsd/dtd based). Possible it will be useful for you as well. It's a bit old, but works well in recent versions of eclipse (3.x). [List of it's features](http://xmlbuddy.com/2.0/features.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing them by hand! WSDLs seem a bit intimidating at first, but are actually fairly simple as long as you are comfortable with XML.

I have written a tutorial on [writing WSDLs](http://blog.gamatam.com/2011/01/writing-wsdl-11-web-service-contract-by.html) and would love feedback:

Answer (score 0):

To write XML/XSL files you can use [oxygenxml](http://www.oxygenxml.com/eclipse_plugin.html)

Or the free version of [editix](http://free.editix.com/)