# Eclipse plugin for edit XML

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the single best free Eclipse plugin for authoring and editing XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435084/what-is-the-single-best-free-eclipse-plugin-for-authoring-and-editing-xml-documen)

Could you please help me and say what kind of free eclipse plugins for editing xml is better?
Thanks.