# What eclipse plugin should I use for HTML5 and XML editing?

Tags: xml, eclipse, html

Anyone care to share their favorite eclipse plugins for html5 and xml coding?

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/xml?page=3

This thread is closed
[What is the single best free Eclipse plugin for authoring and editing XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435084/what-is-the-single-best-free-eclipse-plugin-for-authoring-and-editing-xml-docume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best eclipse plugin for web development at the moment is [Aptana](http://aptana.org/products/studio3) .

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time of this question. Now in 2018 Eclipse is more powerful and has a better support for web development with [CodeMix](https://www.genuitec.com/sox/products/codemix/) plugin. You can take a look of CodeMix features like content assist and fast typing snippets to formatting and real time validation [here](https://www.genuitec.com/sox/tech/html5-with-codemix/).

Answer (score 1):

The standard WTP Eclipse offers a good XML editor.